# Why didn't the Israelites fight against being enslaved?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashas-shemos, egypt, slave-serve-eved-avadim

In Parashat Shemot, the pasuk says

> וַיֹּאמֶר, אֶל-עַמּוֹ:  הִנֵּה, עַם בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל--רַב וְעָצוּם, מִמֶּנּוּ

Pharaoh was, for whatever reason, worried that the Israelites had become more numerous than the Egyptians, so he imposed extra taxes on them and eventually enslaved them. But if the Israelites were actually greater in numbers than the Egyptians, why did they submit to slavery? Why didn't they fight back against their oppression? They should have been able to overcome with their greater numbers.

Comment: Related: [Were Bene-Israel more numerous than the Egyptians according to Exodus 1:9](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/125800/1368)?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, Mefarshim quoted are from [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/1.9#e0n6):

Part 1: Were the Jews actually greater in number than the Egyptians?

Ralbag, Chizkuni, R"A Ben Harambam and others explain that obviously the Jewish population had not grown larger than the population of the entire Egypt, rather, they were growing at a greater rate than the Egyptians, who feared that at some point the Jews would eventually outnumber them.  This approach can be read into the Passuk (1:9) וַיֹּ֖אמֶר אֶל־עַמּ֑וֹ הִנֵּ֗ה עַ֚ם בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל רַ֥ב וְעָצ֖וּם מִמֶּֽנּוּ in one of two ways - either "they will soon be greater and stronger than us" or "they are multiplying and strengthening faster than us" (see Mefarshim).

Others (RDZ Hoffman, see also [Nechama Leibowitz](http://www.nechama.org.il/pages/109.html)) suggest that Pharaoh simply lied to the nation in order to convince them. Daat Mikra (Shemos 1:9, fn16) notes a number of parallels including Bereishis 26:26, Bamidbar 22:6.

There are, however, some commentaries and Targumin that (possibly) understand Pharaoh's comment to be literal.  The most significant and clearly stated would be Ramban 1:10, who gives a number of reasons why Pharaoh did not attack Benei Yisrael directly, the third of which is that the Jews were as strong as the Egyptians at that point.  According to those Mefarshim, we must see how the Egyptians enslaved them.

Part 2: How did the Egyptians enslave them?

Ramban, based on the above, follows many Mefarshim in explaining that the Egyptians tricked them into working for them as "taxes" (see 1:11), which began to slowly weaken them, and the Egyptians were eventually able to kill the Jewish male children as well.  There are a number of adaptations of this understanding within the other commentaries, but almost all of them work within a similar framework.

The famous Chazal on this is found in [Sotah 11b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%91), where the word "Befarech" (1:13) is explained as "Befeh Rach", with soft words, that the Egyptians convinced them and paid them to work originally (Rashi there in above link).  This is quoted by Chizkuni 5:4, Daas Zekeinim 1:11 and 5:4, and [many others](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Search?mode=basic&p=1&c=0&s=1&t=%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%94%20%D7%A8%D7%9A&distance=2&inorder=1&en=1&notes=1).

In conclusion, even according to those Mefarshim who felt that the Jewish nation were strong enough to take on the Egyptians before the enslavement occured, once they were already enslaved, they were certainly too weak and broken to fight back, as evidenced by the rest of the Parsha and the commentaries brought above.

Comment: @sam thanks, I am trying to be marbitz it, as it is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Slavery was normal. Slavery was so normal that Hebrew uses the same word/root for slave as for work. Almost all nations had slaves, Jews had slaves, often times even slaves had slaves. I say this to highlight that slavery was a different institution than what was experienced in the Southern US, because in the ancient world being a slave actually had perks compared to the harsh realities of life that we often don't experience now. So on its surface ancient people didn't always feel a need to rebel against slavery. Being a slave meant you didn't have to strive for your livelihood which meant you didn't have to starve because your food and housing was always provided for, and depending on local rules (like found in the Torah) you could be guaranteed certain rights as a slave.

But just like employers, some slave owners treated their subordinates fairly, and others didn't. And also like employers, a new manager or owner can come to power who changes the whole dynamic for the worse. I would argue that by the time we open up the book of Exodus the Israelites had already consented to being slaves for a while (like nearly all the other Egyptians) and were satisfied with the arrangement. Until a new Pharoah rose to power who decided to make the slavery bad for the Israelites in particular by putting task masters to treat them harshly during their work.

I mention that the Israelites were probably already slaves for a few reasons.

1. We read all about how Joseph enacts laws that basically turn the entire Egyptian population [other than Egyptian priests] into slaves. Most people remember reading these rules, but they forget the opening and closing clauses in the Torah narrative. First we read that in the time of this great famine as the Israelites are moved to Goshen that Joseph is the one who sustains all of them, ***while he is enacting legislation to turn the entire population into slaves.*** This becomes important because the narrative ends with telling us that these laws leading to a nation of slavery is going to be the law moving forward.

Genesis 47:12-27

> יב  וַיְכַלְכֵּל יוֹסֵף אֶת-אָבִיו וְאֶת-אֶחָיו, וְאֵת כָּל-בֵּית
> אָבִיו--לֶחֶם, לְפִי הַטָּף.  12 **And Joseph sustained his father, and
> his brethren, and all his father's household, with bread, according to
> the want of their little ones.** יג  וְלֶחֶם אֵין בְּכָל-הָאָרֶץ,
> כִּי-כָבֵד הָרָעָב מְאֹד; וַתֵּלַהּ אֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם, וְאֶרֶץ כְּנַעַן,
> מִפְּנֵי, הָרָעָב.    13 And there was no bread in all the land; for the
> famine was very sore, so that the land of Egypt and the land of Canaan
> languished by reason of the famine. יד  וַיְלַקֵּט יוֹסֵף,
> אֶת-כָּל-הַכֶּסֶף הַנִּמְצָא בְאֶרֶץ-מִצְרַיִם וּבְאֶרֶץ כְּנַעַן,
> בַּשֶּׁבֶר, אֲשֶׁר-הֵם שֹׁבְרִים; וַיָּבֵא יוֹסֵף אֶת-הַכֶּסֶף,
> בֵּיתָה פַרְעֹה.  14 And Joseph gathered up all the money that was
> found in the land of Egypt, and in the land of Canaan, for the corn
> which they bought; and Joseph brought the money into Pharaoh's house.
> טו  וַיִּתֹּם הַכֶּסֶף, מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם וּמֵאֶרֶץ כְּנַעַן,
> וַיָּבֹאוּ כָל-מִצְרַיִם אֶל-יוֹסֵף לֵאמֹר הָבָה-לָּנוּ לֶחֶם,
> וְלָמָּה נָמוּת נֶגְדֶּךָ:  כִּי אָפֵס, כָּסֶף.   15 And when the money
> was all spent in the land of Egypt, and in the land of Canaan, all the
> Egyptians came unto Joseph, and said: 'Give us bread; for why should
> we die in thy presence? for our money faileth.' טז  וַיֹּאמֶר יוֹסֵף
> הָבוּ מִקְנֵיכֶם, וְאֶתְּנָה לָכֶם בְּמִקְנֵיכֶם--אִם-אָפֵס, כָּסֶף.
> 16 And Joseph said: 'Give your cattle, and I will give you [bread]
> for your cattle, if money fail.' יז  וַיָּבִיאוּ אֶת-מִקְנֵיהֶם,
> אֶל-יוֹסֵף, וַיִּתֵּן לָהֶם יוֹסֵף לֶחֶם בַּסּוּסִים וּבְמִקְנֵה
> הַצֹּאן וּבְמִקְנֵה הַבָּקָר, וּבַחֲמֹרִים; וַיְנַהֲלֵם בַּלֶּחֶם
> בְּכָל-מִקְנֵהֶם, בַּשָּׁנָה הַהִוא.  17 And they brought their cattle
> unto Joseph. And Joseph gave them bread in exchange for the horses,
> and for the flocks, and for the herds, and for the asses; and he fed
> them with bread in exchange for all their cattle for that year. יח
> וַתִּתֹּם, הַשָּׁנָה הַהִוא, וַיָּבֹאוּ אֵלָיו בַּשָּׁנָה הַשֵּׁנִית
> וַיֹּאמְרוּ לוֹ לֹא-נְכַחֵד מֵאֲדֹנִי, כִּי אִם-תַּם הַכֶּסֶף
> וּמִקְנֵה הַבְּהֵמָה אֶל-אֲדֹנִי:  לֹא נִשְׁאַר לִפְנֵי אֲדֹנִי,
> בִּלְתִּי אִם-גְּוִיָּתֵנוּ וְאַדְמָתֵנוּ.    18 And when that year was
> ended, they came unto him the second year, and said unto him: 'We will
> not hide from my lord, how that our money is all spent; and the herds
> of cattle are my lord's; there is nought left in the sight of my lord,
> but our bodies, and our lands. יט  לָמָּה נָמוּת לְעֵינֶיךָ,
> גַּם-אֲנַחְנוּ גַּם אַדְמָתֵנוּ--קְנֵה-אֹתָנוּ וְאֶת-אַדְמָתֵנוּ,
> בַּלָּחֶם; וְנִהְיֶה אֲנַחְנוּ וְאַדְמָתֵנוּ, עֲבָדִים לְפַרְעֹה,
> וְתֶן-זֶרַע וְנִחְיֶה וְלֹא נָמוּת, וְהָאֲדָמָה לֹא תֵשָׁם.   19
> Wherefore should we die before thine eyes, both we and our land? buy
> us and our land for bread, and we and our land will be bondmen unto
> Pharaoh; and give us seed, that we may live, and not die, and that the
> land be not desolate.' כ  וַיִּקֶן יוֹסֵף אֶת-כָּל-אַדְמַת מִצְרַיִם,
> לְפַרְעֹה, כִּי-מָכְרוּ מִצְרַיִם אִישׁ שָׂדֵהוּ, כִּי-חָזַק עֲלֵהֶם
> הָרָעָב; וַתְּהִי הָאָרֶץ, לְפַרְעֹה.     20 So Joseph bought all the
> land of Egypt for Pharaoh; for the Egyptians sold every man his field,
> because the famine was sore upon them; and the land became Pharaoh's.
> כא  וְאֶת-הָעָם--הֶעֱבִיר אֹתוֹ, לֶעָרִים:  מִקְצֵה גְבוּל-מִצְרַיִם,
> וְעַד-קָצֵהוּ.    21 And as for the people, he removed them city by
> city, from one end of the border of Egypt even to the other end
> thereof. כב  רַק אַדְמַת הַכֹּהֲנִים, לֹא קָנָה:  כִּי חֹק לַכֹּהֲנִים
> מֵאֵת פַּרְעֹה, וְאָכְלוּ אֶת-חֻקָּם אֲשֶׁר נָתַן לָהֶם
> פַּרְעֹה--עַל-כֵּן, לֹא מָכְרוּ אֶת-אַדְמָתָם.    22 Only the land of
> the priests bought he not, for the priests had a portion from Pharaoh,
> and did eat their portion which Pharaoh gave them; wherefore they sold
> not their land. כג  וַיֹּאמֶר יוֹסֵף אֶל-הָעָם, הֵן קָנִיתִי אֶתְכֶם
> הַיּוֹם וְאֶת-אַדְמַתְכֶם לְפַרְעֹה; הֵא-לָכֶם זֶרַע, וּזְרַעְתֶּם
> אֶת-הָאֲדָמָה.    23 Then Joseph said unto the people: 'Behold, I have
> bought you this day and your land for Pharaoh. Lo, here is seed for
> you, and ye shall sow the land. כד  וְהָיָה, בַּתְּבוּאֹת, וּנְתַתֶּם
> חֲמִישִׁית, לְפַרְעֹה; וְאַרְבַּע הַיָּדֹת יִהְיֶה לָכֶם לְזֶרַע
> הַשָּׂדֶה וּלְאָכְלְכֶם, וְלַאֲשֶׁר בְּבָתֵּיכֶם--וְלֶאֱכֹל
> לְטַפְּכֶם.   24 And it shall come to pass at the ingatherings, that ye
> shall give a fifth unto Pharaoh, and four parts shall be your own, for
> seed of the field, and for your food, and for them of your households,
> and for food for your little ones.' כה  וַיֹּאמְרוּ, הֶחֱיִתָנוּ;
> נִמְצָא-חֵן בְּעֵינֵי אֲדֹנִי, וְהָיִינוּ עֲבָדִים לְפַרְעֹה.     25 **And
> they said: 'Thou hast saved our lives. Let us find favour in the sight
> of my lord, and we will be Pharaoh's slaves'** כו  וַיָּשֶׂם אֹתָהּ
> יוֹסֵף לְחֹק עַד-הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה עַל-אַדְמַת מִצְרַיִם,
> לְפַרְעֹה--לַחֹמֶשׁ:  רַק אַדְמַת הַכֹּהֲנִים, לְבַדָּם--לֹא הָיְתָה,
> לְפַרְעֹה.    26 **And Joseph made it a statute concerning the land of
> Egypt unto this day, that Pharaoh should have the fifth; only the land
> of the priests alone became not Pharaoh's.**   כז  וַיֵּשֶׁב יִשְׂרָאֵל
> בְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם, בְּאֶרֶץ גֹּשֶׁן; וַיֵּאָחֲזוּ בָהּ, וַיִּפְרוּ
> וַיִּרְבּוּ מְאֹד.    27 *And Israel dwelt in the land of Egypt, in the
> land of Goshen; and they got them possessions therein, and were
> fruitful, and multiplied exceedingly.*

To sum up this giant block of text. Joseph is the one financially sustaining his family who moved to Egypt and he did his best to set them up well. Joseph also enacted a really harsh policy over the entire country of Egypt in which the entire population will become some sort of slave to Pharaoh eventually. And the giant block of text ends saying that this policy will be the law moving forward, even after the famine is over, and the Israelites remained living in Egypt under this policy. The Torah is setting you up to ask the following question: "What will happen to the Israelites in Egypt once Joseph dies and cannot financially sustain them anymore?" My answer is: They will and did become slaves to Pharaoh like the rest of the population, and saw themselves as better off than most because they were able to remain in the land of Goshen while the rest of the Egyptian population would be shifted and moved around according to the needs of the government.

2. We find some odd statements in later narratives in which the Israelites look back on their time as slaves and mention things that don't sound like the terrible policies we read at the beginning of Exodus. For example, we don't see anywhere in sefer Shemot in which an Israelite buys food. But we do read about how the Egyptians "gave them" bread, leeks, melons, and fish for "free." Which should beg the question, ***why?***

Exodus 16:3

> ג  וַיֹּאמְרוּ אֲלֵהֶם בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל, מִי-יִתֵּן מוּתֵנוּ
> בְיַד-יְהוָה בְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם, בְּשִׁבְתֵּנוּ עַל-סִיר הַבָּשָׂר,
> בְּאָכְלֵנוּ לֶחֶם לָשֹׂבַע:  כִּי-הוֹצֵאתֶם אֹתָנוּ אֶל-הַמִּדְבָּר
> הַזֶּה, לְהָמִית אֶת-כָּל-הַקָּהָל הַזֶּה בָּרָעָב.  {ס}  3
>
> and the
> children of Israel said unto them: 'Would that we had died by the hand
> of the LORD in the land of Egypt, when we sat by the flesh-pots, when
> we did eat bread to the full; for ye have brought us forth into this
> wilderness, to kill this whole assembly with hunger.' {S}

Numbers 11:4-5

> ד  וְהָאסַפְסֻף אֲשֶׁר בְּקִרְבּוֹ, הִתְאַוּוּ תַּאֲוָה; וַיָּשֻׁבוּ
> וַיִּבְכּוּ, גַּם בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל, וַיֹּאמְרוּ, מִי יַאֲכִלֵנוּ
> בָּשָׂר.
>
> 4 And the mixed multitude that was among them fell a lusting; and the
> children of Israel also wept on their part, and said: 'Would that we
> were given flesh to eat!
>
> ה  זָכַרְנוּ, אֶת-הַדָּגָה, אֲשֶׁר-נֹאכַל בְּמִצְרַיִם, חִנָּם; אֵת
> הַקִּשֻּׁאִים, וְאֵת הָאֲבַטִּחִים, וְאֶת-הֶחָצִיר וְאֶת-הַבְּצָלִים,
> וְאֶת-הַשּׁוּמִים.
>
> 5 We remember the fish, which we were wont to eat in Egypt for nought;
> the cucumbers, and the melons, and the leeks, and the onions, and the
> garlic;

So the Egyptians apparently gave Israelites their fill of free expensive food during a time in history where a day laborer typically only earned enough for one serving of bread? Keep in mind even people who might be considered wealthy like Jacob can find them and their family starving because of a local famine and riches can turn to rags in just a few years. And so I find it unlikely that the Egyptians were so generous that they fed these neighboring Israelites good food day in and day out without charge for *hundreds of years*. Rather the more likely explanation is that these Egyptians were feeding their Israelite slaves well to try and keep them content and it was working just fine until a new Pharaoh rose to power.

Based on this I would argue the Israelites initially accepted slavery in order to not die from the famine that was impacting all of Canaan and Egypt. This slavery was tolerable for them as it was a better slavery compared to the slavery other Egyptian was facing, so what is there to fight or rebel against?

But then at some point the new Pharaoh rose to power and started inflicting them and so now we find the Israelites not just in slavery, but in immoral and torturous slavery. And it seems like at this point the tides had turned against the Israelites so much that they didn't have a way to fight back or protect themselves anymore after being slaves for such a long time. And so when we open the book of exodus we find a people not recently enslaved, but generationally enslaved and who have lost the ability to fight back in a meaningful way. Which is why God suddenly re-enters the picture to help them.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking in a wrong pond by trying to find "natural causes" to it.

**The Jews were enslaved because they knew they should be enslaved.**
They had the prophecy and the tradition, and they knew the benefits of their enslavement.

When Abraham asked G-d how will he inherit the land, G-d prophesized him with the Egypt exile. The Ariz"l's tradition says G-d wanted them to totally lose their materialism and to become "disconnected" from the physical. Then they will be ready to receive the Torah and be entitled to inherit the Promised Land. Think about going to the dentist. Your kid might ask why you've been hurt. But you'll explain that was made on purpose.

The Jews knew sooner or later that will come. Although some claim that they could replace enslavement with learning Torah, but this does not seem possible after the prophecy.

That desire (to fulfill the prophecy) was so strong, they didn't want to end it prematurely when Moses came only 86 years after it started, instead of the promised 400 (there are different ways of counting it). Moses explained how the rest of slavery can be exchanged for Matan Torah and more.

Comment: Sources? In addition, this while idea is counterintuitive and against the simple reading of many, many pesukim and maamarei chazal, which imply or state clearly that the Jews did not why to be slaves. Plus, which counting says that they would be slaves for 4100 years?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות You miss the whole point of the G-d's prophecy. Why did G-d say that? Why the 400 years were needed at all? What was the point of going down to Egypt? If you can't answer those question, you won't understand why would the Jews want it.

Comment: I can't read God's mind, so I don't have definitive answers to those questions, but your answer does not stand on its own. For example, according to this approach, why didn't the Jews try to get enslaved by Egypt earlier on? Certainly the great Shevatim wanted to fulfill Hashem's prophecy even more than the assisted Jews later on!

Comment: Also, according to this approach, why did some Jews flee Mitzraim 30 years early, if they wanted to be enslaved? Or rejoice when Moshe came to take them out? To the contrary, they should have rejoiced when Paroh increased their burden according to your logic, yet we see that they complained.

Comment: @DonielF Here's what I've learned in "the Scientific method" course in the Hebrew Uni: of two theories being equal, one that explains more phenomena wins. I always try to see the forest from the trees. Unfortunately, most interpreters focus on trees, explaining only minor facts. I would love to discuss this subject if you seriously want to understand the whole idea of the Egyptian Exile - why did Abraham went down, why Yosef was sold, what Moses thought and many more.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Do you want to discuss my theory or just discard it? Meanwhile you agree yo can't answer some simple question my theory does.

Comment: @AlBerko happy to discuss.  I'm not sure which questions I can't answer - I can also say that G-d had them go down to Egypt to "purify them" or prepare them to receive the Torah (if I so choose to), but that doesn't mean that they have to have known that reason at the time, and therefore happily accepted slavery because of it!

Comment: @רבותמחשבות So the Jews had the prophecy, Abraham went down to Egypt to start working on it. So do you agree that the Jews knew about the 400 years of slavery or not?

Comment: It's unlikely that they did

Comment: Abraham definitely did not go to Egypt to "start working on it"...