# Were Bene-Israel more numerous than the Egyptians according to Exodus 1:9?

Tags: history, yetziat-mitzrayim, shemot-exodus, pharaoh

> *Exodus 1:9 He said to his people, “Look, the Israelite people are more numerous and more powerful than we. 10 Come, let us deal shrewdly with them, or they will increase and, in the event of war, join our enemies and fight against us and escape from the land.”*

Had Bene-Israel more population than the Egyptians then?

Or may be it was a kind of exaggeration from the mouth of the Pharaoh, the sort of exaggeration in which unprincipled persons indulge when they would justify themselves for taking an extreme and unusual course?

Comment: the commentators suggest all sorts of reasonings here from "the Jews had amassed financial wealth through underhanded practices which made them stronger" to "their birthrate is higher" to "their God is stronger" to "on the level of man-to-man, their soldiers are stronger."

Comment: Not all [translations of the verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.1.9?lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en) give it that way: [JPS 1917](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0201.htm#9) has it ".. _the people of the children of Israel are too many and too mighty for us_", suggesting they were numerous enough to be a problem/threat, but not [necessarily] that they were more numerous than the Egyptians.

Comment: many commentaries prefer the translation: that  Bene-Israel actually outnumber his own people. because according to them ,elsewhere the expression carries comparative force (“far more numerous than” [Num. 14:12; Deut. 9:14]; “much larger than” [Deut. 7:1]; “greater and more populous than” [Deut. 4:38; 9:1]; “stronger than we” [1 Kings 20:23]; “stronger than I” [2 Sam. 22:18]).